# Scrapy: extracting info from a specific div

Tags: python, web, scrapy, web-crawler

This is my code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'uuid': 'user', 'password': 'cons'},
        callback=self.after_login
    )

def after_login(self, response):
    # check login succeed before going on
    if "authentication failed" in response.body:
        self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
else:
    self.log('LOGGED')  
    sel = Selector(response)
    sel.xpath("//div[@class='amount cSpringGreen']/text()").extract()
```

But nothing appears when I execute it. The way it should work is after login in a website show that information. The html code is this.

```
<h1 class="hide2"></h1>
<div id="vodaint-local" class="wrapper rhomb">
<div class="spring">
<script type="text/javascript">
<div class="mod mod-selectsizeheader vodaint-local">
<div id="mivf" class="content">
<div id="navigation-breadcrumb" class="belt">
<div class="belt">
<div class="miVFR">
<div class="mainMiVF cf">
<div class="headerMiVF cf">
<div class="bodyMiVF cf">
<div class="mainNav" style="height: auto;">
<div class="mainContent withHeader" style="height: 585px;">
<style>
<div id="contentSpinner" style="margin-bottom: 432px; display: none;">
<script>
<section>
<script type="text/javascript">
<div class="mainContentContainer home">
<div class="headerBanner">
<script type="text/javascript">
<div class="lineContainer ">
<h6 class="topHeading prepago"> </h6>
<div class="columnGroup cf">
<div class="column newPromo">
<div class="columnContent">
<p class="cTitle"> Tu saldo</p>
--THIS IS THE INFO I WANT TO SHOW--
<div class="amount cSpringGreen">
0,
<span> 96</span>
€
</div>
```

Thanks!

EDIT: in this pastebin you can find the whole HTML file http://pastebin.com/B2HpACCw the thing that I want to show after the login is "0'96", THANKS!

Comment: The HTML is a little bit weird. There are lots of not closed `div` and `script`. And even a suspicious `style` element.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the exact problem -- is any of the messages on the ``after_login`` method being printed at all? What's the problem exactly: the spider isn't logging in on the site or it is but the data is not being scraped?

Comment: The login works perfectly, it shows  LOGGED on the screen, the problem is after that it doesn't show anything.

Comment: I just ran xpath with the html that you have posted and it works. can you post the real url? then we can test your whole code

Comment: I can't post the real URL as it's a page qhere you enter after a login and it shows personal information, but im goning to edit my question with the complete html code

Answer (score 0):

Store it into item edit; items.py

```
class TestItem(scrapy.Item):
    text= scrapy.Field()
```

and then in spider as

```
item=TestItem()
item['text'] = sel.xpath("//div[@class='amount cSpringGreen']/text()").extract()
print item['text']
```

Comment: I had to modify  desc = scrapy.Field() for  text. = scrapy.Field(). After that it prompts this. 2014-11-26 12:35:48+0100 [login] DEBUG: LOGGED
[]. The item is empty.

Comment: Sorry for the discrepancy, I just forgot to update... Now you have to include the item in items.py and then access it from your spider